# Is it possible to use unicode characters with ruby/tk?

Tags: ruby, windows, unicode, tk-toolkit

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 7 with Tk interface. In the following simple example, if i click a button, GUI will return me a "??????" string instead of "привет" displayed. Is it possible to get back actual unicode string entered?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# coding:utf-8 vi:et:ts=2
require 'tk'
TkRoot.new.tap { |o|
  $edit = TkEntry.new( o ).tap { |o|
    o.pack( :side => 'left' )
    o.insert( 0, "привет" )
  }
  TkButton.new( o, :text => "click me" ).tap { |o|
    o.pack( :side => 'left' )
    o.bind( '1' ) {
      ##  In this place i want unicode, but got garbage :(
      puts( $edit.get().encoding.name )
      puts( $edit.get().inspect )
    }
  }
  o.mainloop()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I checked in Windows and got it working. I'd recommend you put this at the top of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -Ku
require 'tk'
# etc.
```

The `# coding` bit is unnecessary; the `-Ku` flag tells Ruby to use the Unicode codepage. While my testing on Mac doesn't seem to have this issue (either appending `-Ku` or using `# coding: utf-8` will work), it is indeed occurring in Windows. I'm running the same versions as you, just in Parallels.

Alternatively, you could delete the shebang part and run the file with `ruby -Ku test.rb`

**Original answer:**
Yes, although the solution I'm accustomed to would be using UTF-8. You just have to put `# coding: utf-8` on the top line of your file and Ruby will mystically switch over to processing strings in UTF-8:

```
# coding: utf-8
require 'tk'
TkRoot.new.tap { |o|
# etc.
```

For further reading, I'd suggest [this link](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings) which goes over how Ruby thinks about encoding.

Comment: Unfortunately, my file already have corresponding shebang :(. Otherwise, non-ascii text in it, the "привет" string, is not correctly handled. I have modified my question to reflect this.

Comment: @EyeofHell Okay, I just checked on my Windows install. Windows Ruby is indeed pickier about encoding, but it's easily solved with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby -Ku` at the top of your file.

Comment: Clarification: Tk itself is quite happy with Unicode on all platforms, but Ruby *must* be properly told what the encoding of the source file is for the characters in it to be understood.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to avoid the `-Ku` 'hack', you must specify the UTF-8 encoding, not just in your own Ruby source file, but also by telling Tk about it, in some way. (Ruby's Tk wrapper has its own source files, of course.)

I slightly modified your program (and noted the changes). Now it works for me on Windows 7, using Ruby 2.2.5 (including Tk 8.5.12):

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# coding:utf-8 vi:et:ts=2
require 'tk'
Tk::Encoding.encoding = ''.encoding  # Tell Tk which encoding to use (I added this line).
TkRoot.new.tap { |o|
  $edit = TkEntry.new( o ).tap { |o|
    o.pack( :side => 'left' )
    o.insert( 0, "привет" )
  }
  TkButton.new( o, :text => "click me" ).tap { |o|
    o.pack( :side => 'left' )
    o.bind( '1' ) {
      ##  In this place i want unicode, but got garbage :(
      puts( $edit.get().encoding.name )
      puts( $edit.get().inspect )
      puts( $edit.get() )  # See the result (I added this line).
    }
  }
  o.mainloop()
}
```

On the console, the result I get is:

```
UTF-8
"\u043F\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"
привет
```